# How to define labels for goto in C++ outside main function?

Tags: c++, label, goto

Is it possible to use the goto statement in C/C++ to jump to a label outside of the main function? Something like:

```
lab0: //First label
std::cout<<"Hello, ";
goto lab1;

lab1: //Second label
std::cout<<"World!";
goto lab2;

int main()
{
    goto lab0;
    lab2: //Third label
    std::cout<<std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Is there something I'm not getting about the goto and label statements? And yes, i know that the goto and label statements are bad form in general for programming, but they are really helpful for getting out of deeply nested loops and stuff like that.

Comment: *How to define labels for goto in C++*  -- What????  *but they are really helpful for getting out of deeply nested loops and stuff like that.*  That is not what your intention is here.  You're turning the code into spaghetti.

Comment: You cannot have executable statements in the global space.

Comment: Nope. The label is local to the function.

Comment: @A.S.H Thanks for the info. I'll see if I can re-work the statements.

Comment: Why would you ever need `goto` out of the main function if all you want to do is leave deeply nested loops? As an aside, try to avoid deeply nested loops.

Comment: Just for curiosity, I would like to see the real case where you need to do that

Comment: It is absolutely possible to jump to a label outside of `main` function, as long as the jump originates in the same function. It's not possible, however, to have a label or code outside a function altogether, or to jump from one function to another function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, but if you really, really, really need it--and you almost certainly don't--the [setjmp](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/program/setjmp) function may work for you.  Can't execute global statements that can't exist, but can jump directly into the middle of functions and such.